# Why does this ":lt" not work in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I have figure out the index of the last `p`, it does not work using `$('p:lt(_index)')`. When I replace it with number, it works. Why?

```js
$(function() {
  var _index = $('p:last').index();
  console.log(_index);
  $('p:lt(_index)').css('color', 'red');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <p>1</p>
  <p>12</p>
  <p>123</p>
  <p>1234</p>
  <p>12345</p>
  <p>123456</p>
  <p>1234567</p>
  <p>12345678</p>
  <p>123456789</p>
</div>
```

Comment: what the debugger is saying?

Comment: It sure does work.. It just couldnt find `:lt(_index)`. Try `:lt(0)` or `:lt(1)` instead.. Can you see what you did wrong there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the string `'_index'` as argument of the [`:lt()` pseudo-class](https://api.jquery.com/lt-selector/), not using the value of the variable. The line:

```
$('p:lt(_index)').css('color','red');
```

Should be:

```
$('p:lt(' + _index + ')').css('color','red');
```

```js
$(function() {
  var _index = $('p:last').index();
  console.log(_index);
  $('p:lt(' + _index + ')').css('color', 'red');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <p>1</p>
  <p>12</p>
  <p>123</p>
  <p>1234</p>
  <p>12345</p>
  <p>123456</p>
  <p>1234567</p>
  <p>12345678</p>
  <p>123456789</p>
</div>
```